# Add prefix to all Spring Boot actuator endpoints

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Is there an easy way to add a prefix to all the Actuator endpoints?

```
/env ->     /secure/env
/health ->  /secure/health
/info ->    /secure/info
...
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Jesper's answer is completely right, but I was looking for a more straightforward way of prefixing all endpoints, and it can be done with `management.context-path`, e.g.:

```
management:
  context-path: /secure

-> /secure/env
-> /secure/health
...
```

Comment: Changed in Spring Boot 2 to `management.endpoints.web.base-path` https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.x/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-customizing-management-server-context-path

Answer (score 17):

According to current [Spring-Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-monitoring.html), the property to change is:

```
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/secure
```

Comment: please add version to be more explicit

Answer (score 14):

Set the properties `endpoints.{name}.path` in your `application.properties`. For example:

```
endpoints.actuator.path=/secure/actuator
endpoints.env.path=/secure/env
endpoints.health.path=/secure/health
endpoints.info.path=/secure/info
```

To enable security on an endpoint, set `endpoints.{name}.sensitive` to `true`. For example:

```
endpoints.health.sensitive=true
```

See also [Securing sensitive endpoints](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-sensitive-endpoints), [Actuator Security](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security-actuator) and [HTTP health endpoint access restrictions](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-health-access-restrictions) in the Spring Boot reference documentation if you want to secure the actuator endpoints of your application.

See [Common application properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties) in the Spring Boot reference documentation for a list of common properties that you can set in `application.properties`.

Comment: @Steffi things have changed in Spring Boot 2. See the documentation: [Actuator properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#actuator-properties)